# Database connect

Tags: database-connection

Hi i want code about how to connect the ms access database through JAVASCRIPT? and also i need code about insert and delete and update code about that.

Comment: Through javascript running a browser? That's not possible, unless you're talking about a database running on the server and you want to use Ajax so that javascript in the browser can call back to the server to update/query the database on the server... either way, you need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript would typically be running on your user's browser out on the internet, whereas your Access database would certainly not be accessible from the internet, not even indirectly.  If you're looking for a lightweight alternative to SQL Server, the new SQL Server Compact would be worth considering: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0d2357ea-324f-46fd-88fc-7364c80e4fdb&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

Javascript are running in the client machine, but Access database could be store on another one. It is possible to use the web-server (Apache or IIS) and the server-side language (like PHP, ASP, Python, Ruby) to get data from database and to pass it to client as HTML.